# How do I populate my domain model from my repository if my properties have private setters?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories

In the domain core of my application, I have an `Order` object. It has private setters, since those properties should not be modified willy-nilly, but only within the context of performing one of the public functions on the object.

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int MarketplaceId { get; private set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public bool Validate() { //stuff }
    public void Fulfill()
    {
        //messes with order status, etc.
    }

}
```

I have an `OrderRepository` for data access, which lives on the outer edges of my architecture, which has a `GetOrderById(int orderId)` function. This function pulls from the database to populate an `Order` object. I need to be able to populate my `Order` object, but I'd rather not expose the properties as public, since any other application or service utilizing the `Order` object should not be setting those properties. How can I architect this to populate the `Order` object from the repository but still retain my encapsulation on the `Order` object?

It seems like doing this through one or more constructors (overloads) would be messy, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Are you using an ORM? NHibernate can use private fields or protected setters to initialize entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Order is an object but I'm quite certain is NOT a Domain object. Validate() and Fulfill() have no place there, but that's another story.

It doesn't matter if you're using an ORM, it does matter how the object state is stored. In your case the most straighforward way is to either use AutoMapper to map from EF entities to the Order or (and I favor this approach) to have a OrderStateSave DTO which will be passed as a constructor argument.

Personally I prefer to serialize directly the object so restore is a trivial deserialize. To keep it simple, this means I have a column Serialized next to the PK column. It's a additional step when saving but it's easy one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm particularly interested in you OrderStateSave suggestion; that might be the cleanest in my opinion. Also, I think I get your statement against Validate(), if you're going to argue that a domain object should always be valid. Why should Fulfill() not be there?

Comment: An Order is the list of items and quantities a customer ordered. You can say it's a business document. How will Fulfill() fit in there?! The Order might have a Status (Pending, WaitingForProducts, Shipped, Completed etc) but it doesn't do anything, it doesn't have behavior.

Comment: Isn't a domain object a set of properties and behaviors? If it doesn't have behavior, then wouldn't there be no point in making the properties private? The reason they are currently private is so that they are not changed willy-nilly by items outside the object, but instead by the methods encapsulated within the object. Am I missing a concept in DDD?

Comment: A Domain object is modeled after a real life business concept. The rich Domain doesn't mean that you have BIG objects with 15 methods, it means that you have many business concepts and proceses to model. In this particular case the Order object is simple enough. That doesn't mean it isn't important. DDD is all about putting the business in code

Comment: Fulfill() in this case queues the order for fulfillment (maybe QueueForFulfillment() would be a better name). Its current functionality will be to switch the order's status, if the current status allows for it to be switched into the new status (ex: can't fulfill an already-completed order). Is this reasonable to include in the Order object? Where would you suggest such a function live?

Comment: A Service should check if an Order can be fulfilled and then it can queue it up. It's not a part of an Order the behavior to queue itself. There can be specific rules and priority for that which are not the Order responsibility. The Order cares only about the immutable list of the ordered items.

Comment: Is there any behavior you would include in the Order object? Can you give an example of an appropriate behavior for a domain object?

Comment: This is a question for the Domain Expert i.e the person knowing the business very well. What the does the business understand by Order? A domain object should have the behavior required by the business but it has to be the right behavior and this comes only after you understand very well the Domain. There is no rule here, you the developer, have to decide what behavior belongs to which object. Just make sure it's the correct behavior. My Domain might be a bit different than yours so my modeling might be wrong for your specific Domain.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I architect this to populate the Order object from the repository but still retain my encapsulation on the Order object?

You need to use an [Object-relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). [Good ORM](http://nhforge.org/) will allow you to populate private fields so you can have a proper encapsulation in your domain objects.

> It seems like doing this through one or more constructors (overloads) would be messy, but I'm not sure what else to do.

The only requirement NHibernate puts on your domain objects is for it to have an empty private constructor. Also be aware of popular 'Fluent/Code' mappings which make it hard to keep fields private. Instead, you can just use classic HBM mapping files, and catch all potential mapping errors by writing integration tests.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using an ORM (Entity Framework). In this case, I'm trying to populate the domain model from an ORM object. There isn't a 1 to 1 relationship between the two.

Answer (score 0):

By using reflection:

```
var order = new Order();
order
   .GetType()
   .GetProperty("MarketplaceId", BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
   .SetValue(order, 20);
```

There are also several examples which uses delegates for the assignment (to make it faster). Here is an example which I made a couple of years ago: https://webserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#693649

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this interesting [article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/03/31/strengthening-your-domain-avoiding-setters/), it summarizes what you're trying to do: Strengthening your domain by disabling setters.